# Problema ao executar evento com MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Eai galera, tudo certo? Estou com uma dúvida, montei o seguinte SQL

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` EVENT `ut_clear_cart`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY
    1 MINUTE STARTS '2018-11-20 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE
DO
DELETE
FROM
    ut_cart_storage
WHERE
    updated_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

Para limpar a tabela que grava as sessões dos clientes que possuem itens em seu carrinho de compras a cada 10 minutos, mas se eu executo apenas o DELETE ... ele executa mas o evento não, habilitei em meu PhpMyAdmin o event scheduler e nada.
O que está faltando?